# How to interact with an object in a row in a list

Tags: android, list, textview

I have a list in my app. Every row in the list has an image and a textView.

I want the textView to move to the right, when the corresponding row is clicked.

How can I "get" the textView inside the `"setOnItemClickListener"`?

This is my adapter:

```
public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
private final Context context;
private final String[] values;
private TextView textView;
private ImageView icon;
public boolean first;

public MyAdapter(Context context, String[] values) {
    super(context, R.layout.rowlayout, values);
    this.context = context;
    this.values = values;
    this.first = true;
}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rowlayout, parent, false);
    textView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.row_text_view);
    icon = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
    if (first) {
        rowView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        textView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        icon.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        first = false;
        rowView.setClickable(false);
        rowView.setEnabled(false);
    } else {
        rowView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        textView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        icon.setBackgroundDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher));
    }
    textView.setText(values[position]);

    return rowView;
}}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`OnItemClickListener` has method with following signature:

```
onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
```

So you have the row user clicked on. You can now get text view from row:

```
view.findViewById(R.id.row_text_view)`.
```